# Generate RDF graph from CSV triplets

Tags: csv, graph, rdf

I need to convert a CSV file (tab delimited triplets) `[subject predicate object]` into a RDF graph. The CSV file looks something like this:

```
<http://gadm.geovocab.org/id/1_3214_geometry_1km.rdf> 

<http://code.google.com/p/ldspider/ns#headerInfo> _:header14010232801335542310249
_:header14010232801335542310249 <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#responseCode> 200^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer>
_:header14010232801335542310249 <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#date> Fri, 27 Apr 2012 15:58:31 GMT
_:header14010232801335542310249 <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#server> Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
_:header14010232801335542310249 <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#expires> Sat, 28 Apr 2012 15:58:31 GMT
_:header14010232801335542310249 <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#content-length> 4173
```

My knowledge of RDF/RDF Query Language is limited. I would really appreciate any pointers.

Comment: **"CSV file (tab delimited triplets)" `[subject predicate object]`** Um, are they CSV (comma separated values) or TSV (tab separated values), or space delimited with square brackets around them?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the format is already *almost* completely legal RDF (in N-Triples syntax), so it might actually be easiest to just fix a few minor things and then use an RDF parser that support N-Triples format to process the file.

There's two things not quite correct for it to be legal N-Triples:

1. each line should be terminated with a '.'
2. the date values are not written as legal RDF literal values.

Obviously, the first point is trivial to fix. The second is perhaps a little more challenging. An RDF literal in N-Triples syntax is written down as a string in double quotes. So, to convert `Fri, 27 Apr 2012 15:58:31 GMT` to a legal RDF literal, all you'd have to do is put quotes around it:

```
"Fri, 27 Apr 2012 15:58:31 GMT"
```

However, this just makes it a string literal. If you wanted to go a little bit further and actually make it a correctly formatted *datatyped* literal (using the `xsd:dateTime` datatype, you would need to convert it to a proper dateTime formatting. This particular example would need to become `20120327T15:58:31Z`, and in N-Triples a datatype is appended to literal using the `^^<datatype-URL>` syntax, so it would become:

```
"20120327T15:58:31Z"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime>
```

Putting it all together, your the complete line would become:

```
_:header14010232801335542310249 <http://www.w3.org/2006/http#date>  "20120327T15:58:31Z"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> .
```

Alternatively, if you find there are other parts of your CSV file that are problematic to convert, you can also just use any old CSV parser and write a small program that reads the CSV file and creates RDF statements from its values, using an RDF framework/API in the programming language of your choice.